Copy Row to next available row on another sheet
I have created a code to move a row when a field is marked as 'Complete' to another sheet on a separate tab, however it will not move the row to the next available row on the other sheet, it moves it to the next available row outside of the table. Can you please assist? This is the code I have:
Sub MoveRowsToCompletedJobs()
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

' Set the source and target sheets
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP REPORT (ACTIVE)")
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COMPLETED_JOBS")

' Find the last row in the source sheet
lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through each row in the source sheet
For i = 2 To lastRow
' Check if cell in column P contains "COMPLETED"
If sourceSheet.Cells(i, "P").Value = "COMPLETED" Then
' Copy the entire row to the target sheet
sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
' Delete the row from the source sheet
sourceSheet.Rows(i).Delete
' Decrement the loop counter as the rows are shifting up
i = i - 1
' Update the last row value
lastRow = lastRow - 1
End If
Next i
End Sub

Tried the code above and whilst it moved the row to the second tab, it moves to the next available row outside of the table. Is it because one table has more columns than the other?
WIP Report active tab (source sheet)

Completed Jobs sheet


What is the name of the table (if it is the only table on the sheet, we can use index 1)? Which columns are you copying (e.g. A:P)? Are there as many columns as in the table? Is the data in the source worksheet also in a table? If the data is contiguous (no empty rows or columns), you can reference the source range with Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sourceSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion. Then you should copy the rows of the range instead of the entire rows of the worksheet.

Hi BraX - thanks for responding so quickly! To answer your questions 1) The table is the only one on the sheet. Columns are A:R.  Data in the source sheet is also in a table, both tables have the same amount of columns. I will try the source range reference and see how I go - thanks!

Without changing the functionality of your code: you should not change the loop variable manually, that's what the for loop is, well, for.
Sub MoveRowsToCompletedJobs()
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRowTarget As Long
Dim i As Long

' Set the source and target sheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP REPORT (ACTIVE)")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COMPLETED_JOBS")
    
    ' Find the last row in the source sheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in the source sheet
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        ' Check if cell in column P contains "COMPLETED"
        If sourceSheet.Cells(i, "P").Value = "COMPLETED" Then
        ' Copy the entire row to the target sheet
        lastRowTarget = targetSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

        sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, "A")
        ' Delete the row from the source sheet
        sourceSheet.Rows(i).Delete

        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Thanks for the feedback Michal - I copied this code and it didn't work in my sheet.

Move Matching Rows from One Excel Table to Another

Not tested!

Sub MoveRowsToCompletedJobs()
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "WIP REPORT (ACTIVE)"
    Const SRC_TABLE_ID As Variant = 1
    Const SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 16
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "COMPLETED_JOBS"
    Const DST_TABLE_ID As Variant = 1
    Const CRITERIA_STRING As String = "COMPLETED"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects(SRC_TABLE_ID)
    Dim sRowsCount As Long: sRowsCount = slo.ListRows.Count
    If sRowsCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The source table is empty!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If slo.ShowAutoFilter Then
        If slo.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then slo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = slo.DataBodyRange
    
    ' Write the values from the source criteria column to an array.
    Dim sData() As Variant
    With srg.Columns(SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN)
        If sRowsCount = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            sData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            sData = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim surg As Range, r As Long, DeletedRowsCount As Long
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the array and combine the matching rows
    ' into a unioned range.
    For r = 1 To sRowsCount
        If CStr(sData(r, 1)) = CRITERIA_STRING Then
            If surg Is Nothing Then
                Set surg = srg.Rows(r)
            Else
                Set surg = Union(surg, srg.Rows(r))
            End If
            DeletedRowsCount = DeletedRowsCount + 1
        End If
    Next r
    
    If Not surg Is Nothing Then
        ' Reference the destination objects.
        Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
        Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects(DST_TABLE_ID)
        If dlo.ShowAutoFilter Then
            If dlo.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then dlo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dlo.ListRows.Add.Range
        ' Copy and delete matching rows.
        surg.Copy Destination:=drrg
        surg.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    If DeletedRowsCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No completed jobs found!", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox DeletedRowsCount & " job" & IIf(DeletedRowsCount = 1, "", "s") _
            & " moved to ""Completed Jobs"".", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub


Thanks VBasic2008, I tried your code error occurred - Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dlo.ListRows.Add

Sorry. Append .Range, i.e. use Set drrg = dlo.ListRows.Add.Range instead. Corrected.

Updated the code, I now receive a message saying 'No completed jobs found' even though I tested marking two rows as 'Completed'

Sorry. Replace If surg Is Nothing Then with If DeletedRowsCount = 0 Then. Corrected.

Thanks VBasic2008 - edited code - now have error surg.Copy Destination:=drrg

Hi VBasic, the code above moves the row to the bottom of the source sheet, not the target sheet.

Sorry. Replace Set dlo = sws.ListObjects(DST_TABLE_ID) with Set dlo = dws.ListObjects(DST_TABLE_ID). Corrected.

It worked!!!!! Thank you sooooo much :)

If an Excel table (ListObject) exists on targetSheet and includes column A, using End(xlUp) will always identify the last cell in column A within the table, regardless of whether it is blank or not.
Looping through the data rows in reverse order simplifies the code.
Sub MoveRowsToCompletedJobs()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, targetCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the source and target sheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP REPORT (ACTIVE)")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COMPLETED_JOBS")
    
    ' Find the last row in the source sheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in the source sheet
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        ' Check if cell in column P contains "COMPLETED"
        If sourceSheet.Cells(i, "P").Value = "COMPLETED" Then
            ' Copy the entire row to the target sheet
            Set targetCell = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
            If Len(targetCell.Value) = 0 Then
               Set targetCell = targetCell.End(xlUp)
            End If
            sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=targetCell.Offset(1)
            ' Delete the row from the source sheet
            sourceSheet.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub



Thanks taller. Tried your code and it is still pasting outside of the table. What am I missing?

Pls edit your post to share a screenshot about two sheets' layout.
